# how to query mongodb using the $ne operator?

Tags: java, mongodb

i'm trying to do a $ne query in mongodb while using a regex, but it doesn't seem to work. the $ne (not equal) operator works fine when i don't use a regex though.

```
BasicDBObject q = new BasicDBObject()
q.put(field, ["\$ne": value])
```

the above works fine, the result set doesn't contain any documents that has that value for that field.

but i need it to be case insensitive. so i did this

```
q.put(field, ["\$ne": Pattern.compile(value, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)])
```

but this doesn't work..

so i thought, let me go to the command line and see if i can do it manually. so i did this:

```
db.Order.find({"bill.recipient.name": {$ne: /diep/i}},{"bill.recipient.name":1})
```

and it still doesn't work!

any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using **$not** instead of **$ne**.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-Metaoperator%3A%24not

Comment: Yeah - "find objects where field is not equal to this regular expression" is different from "find objects where field does not match this regular expression."

Comment: ahhh your right.. i totally missed that $not operator.  what a subtle difference. thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

You can construct your query this way also

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.append(fieldname,new BasicDBObject("$ne", value));
```